# How to post a java-script object to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

**Here are my Classes (Simplified)**

```
public class DailyMenu
{
  public string MenuNoteText { get; set; }
}

public class MenuMonth
{
  public DailyMenu[] DailyMenus { get; set; }
}
```

**And My webApi Action is**

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddMenuItem_New(MenuMonth menuMonth)
{

}
```

**Clientside code for posting data is :**

[image]

If I check Request.Form[0], I see "sampletext".

in menuMonth, DailyMenus[0] has 1 DailyMenu item... which seems correct.

**but this item's MenuNoteText property is null :(**
I spent more than half day trying to figure this out.. still no results ..
I am sure many must have posted a simple javascript object to server.. Can someone tell me what m I missing here ?

Comment: Can you post your client side script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1):

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded: Form data is encoded as name/value pairs, similar to a URI query string. This is the default format for POST.

Seems you *forget to tell* Web Api that you are sending request in *json* format, add 3 more headers and stringify your Json:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 data: JSON.stringify(menuMonth),
```

Also note that there is one wrong typing: `cache`, not `catche`